# Designated Initializer and NSString Category

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, categories

```
@implementation NSString (StringCategory)

-(id)init{
    self =[super init];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithInput1:(NSString*)input1 input2:(NSString*)input2{

        input1 = [input1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        input2 = [input2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];



        if(input1.length>0 && input2.length>0){
            self = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@###%@",input1,input2];
        }else if(input1.length>0){
            self = input1;
        }else if(input2.length>0){
            self = input2;
        }

    return self;
}
@end
```

The above code results in the following output.
1) input1=a , input2=b

a###b

2) input1=a;

a

3)input2=b

b

It results in following warning

> "Convenience initializer missing a 'self' call to another initializer"

I don't know if the above is efficient or would it cause any issue, as `init` is the designated initialiser (don't know if it could issues with older iOS versions)?

NSString output should be nil, if both input1 and input2 are nil.

Comment: It makes no sense for your `initWithInput1:input2:` method to be an instance method. It should be a class method with a name such as `combineInput1:andInput2:`.

Comment: And don't attempt to override methods in an Objective-C category. It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If `input1.length == 0` and `input2.length == 0`, you don't set `self`, you don't call a `super init`, and you still return `self`. Presumably you want to either set `self = nil` or `return nil` in that case.